# Create pull request at github remote branch and push to that pull request

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I have basic experience with Git - have been working with private projects - but no in-depth knowledge. I am currently in a probation period of joining a company. We have this main Github repo

```
https://github.com/client-company-name/appName.git
```

and in it we have this remote branch

```
https://github.com/client-company-name/appName/tree/stagging
```

I created a pull request from the above and I want to push my local commits to that pull request. I pushed the "Create Pull Request" button at github, which then created this :

```
https://github.com/client-company-name/appName/pull/426
```

How can I push from my local branch into the above pull request remote branch? Once again I am pretty new to advanced git commands, if I use any term wrong, kindly explain to me.

Answer (score 2):

Any commits pushed to `tree/stagging` branch will automatically update the `426` PR.